# Can this table structure work or should it change

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design

I have an existing table which is expected to work for a new piece of functionality. I have the opinion that a new table is needed to achieve the objective and would like an opinion if it can work as is, or is the new table a must?  The issue is a query returning more records than it should, I believe this is why:

There is a table called postcodes.  Over time this has really become a town table because different town names have been entered so it has multiple records for most postcodes. In reference to the query below the relevant fields in the postcode table are:

postcode.postcode - the actual postcode, as mentioned this is not unique
postcode.twcid - is a foreign key to the forecast table, this is not unique either

The relevant fields in the forecast table are:
forecast.twcid - identifyer for the table however not unique because there four days worth of forecasts in the table.  Only ever four, newver more, never less.

And here is the query:

```
select * from forecast 
LEFT OUTER JOIN postcodes ON forecast.TWCID = postcodes.TWCID 
WHERE postcodes.postcode = 3123 
order by forecast.twcid, forecast.theDate;
```

Because there are two records in the postcode table for 3123 the results are doubled up.  Two forecasts for day 1, two for day 2 etc......

Given that the relationship between postcodes and forecast is many to many (there are multiple records in the postcode tables for each postcode and twcid. And there are multiple records for each twcid in the forecast table because it always holds four days worth of forecasts)  is there a way to re-write the query to only get four forecast records for a post code?

Or is my thought of creating a new postcode table which has unique records for each post code necessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem that postcodes can be in multiple towns.  And towns can have multiple postcodes.  In the United States, the US Census Bureau and the US Post Office have defined very extensive geographies for various coding schemes.  The basic idea is that a zip code has a "main" town.

I would suggest that you either create a separate table with one row per postcode and the main town.  Or, add a field to your database indicating a main town.  You can guarantee uniqueness of this field with a filtered index:

```
create unique index postcode_postcode_maintown on postcodes(postcode) where IsMainTown  = 1;
```

You might need the same thing for `IsMainPostcode`.

(Filtered indexes are a very nice feature in SQL Server.)

With this construct, you can change your query to:

```
select *
from forecast LEFT OUTER JOIN
     postcodes
     ON forecast.TWCID = postcodes.TWCID and postcodes.IsMainPostcode = 1
WHERE postcodes.postcode = 3123 
order by forecast.twcid, forecast.theDate;
```

Comment: Thank you for you time and advice.  Can I assume my though was correct, there is no way to achieve it using the current structure? I have recommended that the current postcode table is renamed to towns and a new table for unique postcodes is created.  This how I would have set it up but I need approval to do it.  I had also thought of adding a field however I see defining the mainTown for so many records as a bigger job which does not fix the bad database design.  Thanks again!

Comment: What about creating a view on the postcode table to produce a unique postcode dataset and then join the forecast table to the view.  This seems like reasonable solution if I a not allowed to create a new unique postcode table

Answer (score 0):

You should really never have a table without a primary key. Primary keys are, by definition, unique. The primary key should be the target for your foreign keys.

You're having problems because you're fighting against a poor database design.

Comment: Thank you for your time.  Yes I hear what you are saying IMO 99% of tables should have primary keys.  FYI the postcodes table does have a primary key however this is irrelevant in the forecast query.  I do not however think the forecast table needs one.  Every time there is a new forecast data feed, the entire contents of the table is deleted and the new feed is inserted.  There will never be a situation where forecasts are ever updated or managed in any way, this is why I don't thin a PK is necessary.

Comment: If you have a primary key in the postcode table, why aren't you joining to it?